# GeoKettle Pan/ Kitchen Hangs at New Database Defined

Tags: java, etl

Pan/ Kitchen of 
Spatially enabled version of
Pentaho Data Integration (Kettle) version 3.2 hangs at 'New Database Defined'. I am trying to extract some data from a MS Sql Server 2005 table through a ODBC connection and populate a postgis table. Every time when the transformation reaches "a new database connection defined" it hangs.

Transformation runs flawless in spoon though.

I tried running seperate steps, everything works fine, till the last step is added, when writing to postgis output is inserted this starts happening. Yet if an output to a postgis table done seperately the task runs fine.

Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For questions about GeoKettle, please join the user mailing list at: https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/geokettle-users. Do not hesitate to post your transformation file on the list. It will help in identifying the problem and in solving it.

Cheers,

Comment: Hi Dr Thierry Badard, It is so nice to here from you about an answer for my question. I will definitely post a thread at the mailing list you gave me. We recently integrated geo kettle to populate our postgres based datawarehouse and looking forward to doing more with the same. Great to here that your are there for assistance. Thanks!!!